# Dynamic entityBaseUrl in MetadataGenerator

Tags: java, spring, saml, spring-saml

I have a single web server which serves multiple tenants. Each tenant has it's own hostname. But it seems that `MetadataGenerator` can have only single `entityBaseUrl` at a time.

Is it possible either to use several instances of `MetadataGenerator` or to use dynamically defined `entityBaseUrl` when genetating metadata?

Comment: skozlov, what approach did you follow?

Comment: I don't use `MetadataGenerator` at all. Instead, pre-generated metadata is stored in DB and is fetched in the metadata provider filter.

Comment: Skozlov, would it be possible to share some code?

Comment: Unfortunately, that was private code of the organization I already left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic generation of metadata (MetadataGeneratorFilter + MetadataGenerator) supports only a single hostname. You should use pre-generated metadata (details can be found in the Spring SAML manual), or customize the metadata generation in case you need to support multiple hostnames.